# CodeSchool APIs with Rails - Asserting response location is the same as the specific URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing CodeSchool Surviving APIs with Rails and I'm stuck on a challenge. The question asks "Now, assert the Location response header is a URL that points to the newly created human resource. You will need to parse the response body, so check the test/test_helper.rb file on the secondary tab for a helper method that can help you save some time." The error message I get is "Make sure that you assert the response location is the same as the humans human_url!" Below is the code I have so far.

```
 class CreatingHumansTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'creates human' do  
    post '/humans', { human: { name: 'John', brain_type: 'small' } }.to_json,
      { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON, 'Content-Type' => Mime::JSON.to_s }

    assert_equal 201, response.status
    assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type
    human = json(response.body)
    assert_equal human_url(human[:id]), response.location

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually have it right ... I believe there's something screwy with their code on this particular challenge.

I just ran through it and had to click the "check my work" button on the bottom of the page. Once I clicked that button, it told me I had completed it, etc. However, if I used the "normal" CMD+Enter, it gave me the same error as you received.

Comment: I checked the forum and some people were also experiencing a similar issue. I got it to work now though by clicking on the button. Thanks!